# how to set framerate of usb_cam above 30FPS?

Tags: ros, camera, usb-cam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [this usb_camera](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2MP-CMOS-OV2710-High-30-60-120-fps-Industrial-Mini-1-05mm-Wide-angle-fisheye-lens/32727795207.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.21.722c46e5Zy4PUx&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_5722611_10340_10341_10696_5722911_5722811_5722711_10084_10083_10618_10307_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_5722511,searchweb201603_11,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=1fe968f7-f35e-435a-8cae-9b3de4480f2b-3&algo_pvid=1fe968f7-f35e-435a-8cae-9b3de4480f2b&priceBeautifyAB=0). I want to use the frame rate 120FPS `640x480`.
I passed the parameter `<framerate>` in launch file. But when i check the average rate of topic `rostopic hz usb_cam/image_raw . its showing 30HZ only. Actually it should be 120 !!!

I also try hardcoding the `ros::Rate` to 120, but is doesn't effect the output of average rate.

```
  bool spin(){
   ros::Rate loop_rate(this -> framerate_);
    while (node_.ok())
    {
    if (cam_.is_capturing()) {
    if (!take_and_send_image()) ROS_WARN("USB camera did not respond in time.");
   }
   //ROS_INFO("framerate_ '%i'", framerate_ );
   ros::spinOnce();
   loop_rate.sleep();
}
return true; }
```

Are there any restrictions on increasing the framerate above 30FPS. When I change the frame rate below 30 is show the changes but not above the 30FPS.
My usb_cam launch file parameters are as:

```
  <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
<param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
<param name="image_width" value="640" />
<param name="image_height" value="480" />
<param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
<param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
<param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
<param name="framerate" value="120" />
</node>
```

How can I change the framerate in `usb_cam` above 30FPS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293579/how-to-set-framerate-of-usb_cam-above-30fps?/) by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-08**:
Do you see an option to set the framerate that high using `guvcview`?

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-06-09**:
I want to use with ROS. I think its just a video viewer in linux. if no, please give some link

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-06-09**:
I want to use withROS. I think its just a video viewer in linux. if no, please give some link

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-09**:
If it doesn't work in guvcview then it probably won't work in usb_cam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably set the `pixel_format` to **MJPG**. In the product link you have shared, YUYV supports max 30fps only (make sense because of USB2.0 hardware bandwidth limitation!).

---

Originally posted by [vinaykumarhs2020](https://answers.ros.org/users/21620/vinaykumarhs2020/) with karma: 126 on 2018-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-06-09**:
!!!! This pixel camera is not supported by the camera.

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-07-30**:
Yes, Actually pixel value needed to be changed, I check that yuyv support only max 30 FPS. I changed to mjpeg